# How to add a function which listens to the Audio's current playtime when the user leaves/refreshes the page?

Tags: reactjs, html5-audio

I have inserted an Audio into my React web page. I'm trying to record the current audio playtime of the audio when the user leaves the page (e.g. refresh/jump to a different page) so that the audio can restart from that point when the user revisits the page. My understanding is that I need to add an event listener, or use something like componentWillUnmount. Can anyone help me on this? Thank you.

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class Audio extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { time: 0 };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <audio
        loop
        autoPlay
        currentTime={this.state.time}
        className="backgroundAudio"
        pause={this._onPause}
      >
        <source
          src="example.mp3"
          type="audio/mpeg"
        />
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
      </audio>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook. In your componentDidUnmount get the audio source time lapsed into the redux or app level state, and in case of user comes to this page use componentDidMount to continue the audio source from that time lapse by seeking the audio source.